# Facebook Authentication - adding permission for accessing email address

Tags: email, authentication, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

It might be a basic question.
And also my English is poor...

I have a web service which needs Facebook login.
With JavaScript SDK, I can get users' basic information such as user ID, name, gender.
And now there are about 10000 users.

This time, I need to access users' email address.
I know I can get email address from new users by adding scope attribute.
However, from existed users, though I can access email address, I don't know how to display authorization dialogue for permission to access email address.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code snippet that I have used. Basically check their permissions using /me/permissions and show a reauthenticate link

```
<script>
    var FB_config = {
        API_ID: 123123123123,
        PERMISSIONS: "publish_stream,email",
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // initialise FB
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : FB_config.API_ID,
                status     : true, 
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', FBverifyLogin);
        };
    });

    function FBverifyLogin(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            checkPermissions(); // check permissions if the user is logged in
        }
    }


    function checkPermissions(){
        jQuery("#FBreauth").hide();
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
            var permissions = FB_config.PERMISSIONS.split(",");
            for(var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
            {
                if(response.data[0][permissions[i]] == undefined || response.data[0][permissions[i]] != 1)
                {
                    // user does not have full permissions, show reauth link
                    jQuery("#FBreauth").show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function FBreauth(){
        FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'oauth',
                display: 'popup',
                app_id: FB_config.API_ID,
                client_id: FB_config.API_ID,
                redirect_uri: "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                scope: FB_config.PERMISSIONS
            }
        );
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="FBreauth(); return false;" id="FBreauth">App permissions have changes. Please reauthorize this app</a>
```